# Java file directory for multiple users

Tags: java

i have a plugin which is going to be used more than one client, and the plugin has to access a file to load some arrays in java

```
fFile = new File("file path");
```

I want the path is general,

How can I declare a file path for more than one account?
For example

" C:\users\X\documents\filename" and for another user

" C:\users\Y\documents\filename"  or maybe something 
"C:\users\$username\documents\filename"

Comment: Is users authenticated somehow? And is the plugins environment JavaSE or JavaEE?

Comment: try ** System.getProperty("user.home");** to get the user home directory, then append your path in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `user.home` for this

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "someFileName.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("user.home");` is what you want here - usually it returns the my documents folder on windows and /usr/home on *nix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.getProperty( "user.home" )` to get the home directory of users.
And use that String to compose your path.

Regards,
 Stéphane